# Bootstrap nav bar - How to float down navbar-fixed-top?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I get the following menus to float with the page/body when resizing the browser width-wise?

http://jsfiddle.net/J7jJh/1/show/

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
     // ...
```

Fixed works fine http://jsfiddle.net/WWf3x/show/ but I don't want the nav bar at the top and I can't figure out how to use margin or float with navbar-fixed-top to bring it down and push the body down at the same time and not overlap via scrolling either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is probably possible to push the `navbar-fixed-top` down along with the body, a cleaner solution would be to try and apply the responsive classes to `navbar`, since BootStrap 2.3 does not seem to do so. This would allow you to keep the `navbar-fixed-top` working if you decide to use it in the future or in another layout.

A quick look at the differences between `navbar-fixed-top` and `navbar` in the BootStrap css source code gives us the additions to make to the `css`.

Here is a working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J7jJh/5). Here is the `css` code to add:

```
.navbar .container{
    width: 940px;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar .container
    {
        width: 1170px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .navbar .container
    {
        width: 724px;
    }    
}
```